# How/where can I save Bash scripts on my computer so that my terminal can execute more commands?

Tags: bash, terminal, path

Terminal/Bash has a default set of commands, such as cp, echo, grep,...

I'd like to be able to add a command, like "hello" that I can execute and get a result instead of *-bash: hello: command not found*.

Comment: Not that it matters much, but not all of those are part of `bash`: you can use `type [CMD]` to see whether or not a given command is part of bash or something made available via the system.

Answer (score 4):

You can add custom functions to your `.bashrc` or if you mean actual stand-alone applications, then you could make a directory such as `~/bin` and then add it to the `$PATH` variable in your `.bash_profile` or `.profile` and put any stand-alone applications in said `~/bin` directory.

[Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Functions) is a pretty reliable source for information on functions and other aspects of Bash, along with the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions) and the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/).

NOTE:

If you have a `.profile` you can still use `.bash_profile`, if you choose not to use `.bash_profile`, please be sure to encapsulate any code for Bash within an if-statement since `.profile` is used by other shells:

```sh
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then # BASH_VERSION is defined, therefore we are using BASH
  # BASH CODE
fi
```

To simplify things you could even create functions allowing you to easily run one-liners depending on which shell you're running:

```
ifbash()
{
   if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
     $@
    else
     return 1
   fi
}

ifzsh()
{
   if [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then
     $@
   else
     return 1
   fi
}

# You can use these to conditionally execute commands
# here's a function that prints the type/blueprint of a function
fn-printout()
{
   for y in "$@"; do
     ifbash type "$y" || ifzsh whence -f "$y"
   done
}
```

(Note: while using `[ TEST ]` is not recommended when using Bash, other shells may not understand `[[ TEST ]]`; this is one reason why it is better to simply use `.bash_profile`, instead of `.profile`)

As pointed out in some comments, while you can define variables such as `$PATH` in your `.bashrc`, it is not necessarily recommended as this will cause said variable to be re-set every time you start an interactive session of Bash, resulting in unnecessary computational steps every time you start a new interactive session--it's better to store variables and other environmental changes that only need happen once (such as at login) in `.bash_profile`, or `.profile`, which can then be re-sourced as needed using `bash -l`.

Comment: Editing `PATH` in `.bashrc` is not ideal -- at least on traditional UNIX systems, `.bashrc` is run on every interactive shell, meaning that if you have a shell spawned with another shell as parent, you get content added to the `PATH` twice. On such systems, environment-variable changes make more sense in `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, where they can be run just once by the user's login shell, but not again by every other interactive shell thereafter.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy edited my answer to point out the reasons why not to use `.bashrc` for environmental changes.

Comment: `[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]` -- quotes are important. Otherwise, the command with an empty string becomes `[ -n ]`, which is true (because it's implicitly `[ -n -n ]`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy oh, yeah, I forgot about that: I've gotten used to not needing them with `[[...]]`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify your current [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) and give priority to the paths you care more, for example, you could have a directory in your `$HOME/mycommands` and a PATH like this:

```
PATH="$HOME/mycomands:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin" ...
```

in `$HOME/mycommands` you could have your custom commands that will be called first instead of the ones defined on your system